# How to return a web page from a POST in Express/Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If a form in my website is emitting a POST, and I was the data to be processed and then have them redirected back to "/", how would I handle this?

My current code is

```
app.post('/contact', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.Name)
    console.log(req.body.Email)
    console.log(req.body.TextArea)
    res.end(???)
})
```

This accurately outputs the given variables but I cannot find any information online on how to return a webpage or redirect to another web page.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use res.redirect().

My bad, http.get/request belongs to node, not express. And the way to relocate to a page in node is not even .get(), it's .setHeader('/link') tho, res.end() is mandatory.

Comment: What exactly does res.end() do that I would want it to be called automatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
res.redirect('/');
```

Simple as that.